# A question on Rank of matrices

Tags: matrix-calculus, random-matrices

Let $X_n=X+Y_n$ define a sequence of $m\times m$ random matrices. Let $Y_n$ be such that it converges in probability to a zero matrix. Then can it be that $Rank (X_n)$ for large enough $n$ be bigger than $Rank (X)$?

Is it possible to have $Rank(X)>0$ and come up with a scenario?

Comment: Is $X$ an arbitrary matrix?

Comment: Let $X$ be any non zero matrix.

Comment: Take any matrix $Y$ such that $\text{rank}(X+Y)>\text{rank}(X)$, then $Y_n:=Y/n$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, simply choose $X$ to be the zero matrix and $Y_n$ a sequence of (not necessarily random) nonzero matrices that converge to zero.

**Edit:** You can take any arbitrary $X$ that does not have full rank. Let $Y$ be an invertible matrix. Now note that $\det(tX + Y)$ is a continuous map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that converges to $\det(Y) \ne 0$ for $t \to 0$, i.e. the matrix $\det(tX + Y)$ is invertible for all $t$ with $|t| < \varepsilon$. But this means $\det(X + tY) = t^{-n} \det(tX + Y)$ is nonzero for $0 < t < \varepsilon$, so you can choose the sequence $Y_n = \frac{\varepsilon}{n}Y$.

I assume that a more careful exaimation should reveal that the set of matrices $Y$ so that $X + Y$ does not have full rank is a null set for any fixed matrix $X$.

Comment: Interesting :-) I like this. Can we also think of a nonzero matrix $X$ too?

Comment: Yes, you can actually choose any matrix that does not have full rank.

Comment: Many thanks. I also posted another question as a comment to the answer given by @mfl. Could you please share you opinion on that? Many thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine $$X=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0& 0\end{pmatrix},$$ which has rank one. Now

$$Y_n=\begin{pmatrix}a^{11}_n&a^{12}_n\\a^{21}_n& a^{22}_n\end{pmatrix}.$$ Thus $$Y_n=\begin{pmatrix}1+a^{11}_n&a^{12}_n\\a^{21}_n& a^{22}_n\end{pmatrix}.$$ Can $X_n$ have rank two? It depends on the value of $$a^{22}_n(1+a^{11}_n)-a^{21}_na^{12}_n.$$ Is there any reason for being $0?$ Absolutely not, even if $Y_n\to 0.$ So we can have $\rm{rank}(X_n)>\rm{rank} (X)$ for $n$ big enough. Even more, for all $n.$

Note that if $\rm{rank}(X)=m$ then $\rm{rank}(X_n)\le \rm{rank}(X).$

Comment: Many thanks for the nice example +1. As such there is no reason to believe that a generalized inverse of $X_n$ converges to a gen. inverse of $X$. Can one show this?